# C programming Do while

Tags: c, function

I just wrote this and i cant find problem. I work with codeblocks and it writing this problem

```
error: expected 'while' before '{' token
=== Build finished: 1 errors, 1 warnings)
```

But I cant wrote while there , because its not correct. Can someone help me please? Sorry for my eng.

```
printf("Put numbers for some reason\n");

int cislo;
int s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9;

while(scanf("%d",&cislo)==1){
   if (cislo<0)
      printf ("Cislo %d, je zaporne, takove neberu", cislo);
}

s0=s1=s2=s3=s4=s5=s6=s7=s8=s9=0;


do (cislo/10);
    {
    switch (cislo%10);

    case 0; ++s0;  break;
    case 1; ++s1;  break;
    case 2; ++s2;  break;
    case 3; ++s3;  break;
    case 4; ++s4;  break;
    case 5; ++s5;  break;
    case 6; ++s6;  break;
    case 7; ++s7;  break;
    case 8; ++s8;  break;
    case 9; ++s9;  break;
    }

 while (cislo>0);

 printf("0  %d x \n 1  %d x \n 2  %d x \n 3  %d x \n 4  %d x \n 5  %d x \n 6  %d x \n 7  %d x \n 8  %d x \n 9  %d x \n",s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9);

 return 0;
}
```

In the final it must print something like this:

```
100
Number: 100 include this numbers :
0 ...  2x
1 ...  1x
2 ...  0x
3 ...  0x
4 ...  0x
5 ...  0x
6 ...  0x
7 ...  0x
8 ...  0x
9 ...  0x
```

Comment: You have an extra `;` on the line that starts with `do` and it should actually be `while`, not `do`. You are missing braces in the `switch` statement and have an extra `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do 
{
cislo /= 10;
switch (cislo%10);

case 0; ++s0;  break;
case 1; ++s1;  break;
case 2; ++s2;  break;
case 3; ++s3;  break;
case 4; ++s4;  break;
case 5; ++s5;  break;
case 6; ++s6;  break;
case 7; ++s7;  break;
case 8; ++s8;  break;
case 9; ++s9;  break;
}
```

`while (cislo>0);`

Try this?

Comment: Ok guys, thank you very much for your answers! 

Now it works, not corectly for 100% but it works.

Comment: @user1760185 selecting an answer is Stack Overflow's method of saying "thank you" :-)

Answer (score 1):

A `do .. while` statement has this form:

```
do statement while (expression)
```

In your example you have two statements:

```
(cislo/10);
```

and another compound statement `{ ... }`. This does not make any sense.

Comment: That's a semi-colon, not a comma :)

Comment: since when is do(statement){ }while() correct? It was do{ }while() IIRC?

Comment: @PrototypeStark `(cislo/10);` is actually a valid statement. It is called an *expression statement*:

Comment: @ouah I haven't ever seen anyone use it like that before. Is it in c99 or something? I have always seen do { statements } while(cond);

Comment: `do statement while (expression)` is right. `{ ... }` is a statement also.

Comment: i was trying to point out `condition` as easier to understand - not disagreeing with the {} bit - though you get into trouble if you don't have braces on multiple statements so it's a handy reminder there, too

Answer (score 1):

`do (cislo/10);` should be

```
do 
{ 
  /* your code */ 
} while (cislo/10);
```

Each `case X;` should be `case X:`.

As pointed by hexist, a switch is written like this:

```
switch (condition) {
  case X:
    /*something*/
    break;
}
```

Comment: And there needs to be a brace enclosing the case statements .. ie switch (..) {  and then the closing } at the end

Answer (score 0):

Remove ";" after do() .

```
do (cislo/10)
{
switch (cislo%10);
```

Comment: but keep it after `switch (cislo%10);`?

Comment: No, switch should be like switch(){case:...} . I feel it is better to read some C language book...